# how I combined this 2 queries?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

```
SELECT USERINFO.Name, 
FORMAT((Min(CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME)),"dd-mmm-yyyy") AS DATE_IN, FORMAT((Min(CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME))," hh:mm") AS TIMEIN_am, FORMAT((Max(CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME))," hh:mm") AS TIMEOUT_pm, FORMAT((Min(CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME)),"dd-mmm-yyyy hh:mm") AS DATE_SORT
FROM CHECKINOUT INNER JOIN USERINFO ON CHECKINOUT.USERID=USERINFO.USERID
WHERE (CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME>=DATEVALUE(PERIOD_START) And CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME<DATEADD("d",1,PERIOD_END))
GROUP BY CHECKINOUT.USERID, USERINFO.Name, USERINFO.SSN, DateValue(CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME), USERINFO.Badgenumber
HAVING (((USERINFO.Badgenumber)<"8000"))
ORDER BY USERINFO.Name, Min(CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME);
```

this queries is for timein for am and timeout for pm

```
SELECT USERINFO.Name, FORMAT((Min(CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME)),"dd-mmm-yyyy") AS DATE_IN, FORMAT((Min(CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME))," hh:mm") AS TIMEOUT_am, FORMAT((Max(CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME))," hh:mm") AS TIMEIN_pm, FORMAT((Min(CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME)),"dd-mmm-yyyy hh:mm") AS DATE_SORT
FROM CHECKINOUT INNER JOIN USERINFO ON CHECKINOUT.USERID=USERINFO.USERID
WHERE (CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME>=DATEVALUE(PERIOD_START) And CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME<DATEADD("d",1,PERIOD_END) And FORMAT(CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME,"hh:mm")>"12:00" And FORMAT(CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME,"hh:mm")<"13:00")
GROUP BY CHECKINOUT.USERID, USERINFO.Name, USERINFO.SSN, DateValue(CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME), USERINFO.Badgenumber, FORMAT(CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME,"dd")
HAVING (((USERINFO.Badgenumber)<"8000"))
ORDER BY USERINFO.Name, Min(CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME);
```

and this queries is for timeout for am, and timein for pm

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
SELECT USERINFO.Name, 
FORMAT((Min(CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME)),"dd-mmm-yyyy") AS DATE_IN, FORMAT((Min(CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME))," hh:mm") AS TIMEIN_am, FORMAT((Max(CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME))," hh:mm") AS TIMEOUT_pm, FORMAT((Min(CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME)),"dd-mmm-yyyy hh:mm") AS DATE_SORT
FROM CHECKINOUT INNER JOIN USERINFO ON CHECKINOUT.USERID=USERINFO.USERID
WHERE (CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME>=DATEVALUE(PERIOD_START) And CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME<DATEADD("d",1,PERIOD_END))
GROUP BY CHECKINOUT.USERID, USERINFO.Name, USERINFO.SSN, DateValue(CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME), USERINFO.Badgenumber
HAVING (((USERINFO.Badgenumber)<"8000"))

UNION ALL
SELECT USERINFO.Name, FORMAT((Min(CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME)),"dd-mmm-yyyy") AS DATE_IN, FORMAT((Min(CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME))," hh:mm") AS TIMEOUT_am, FORMAT((Max(CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME))," hh:mm") AS TIMEIN_pm, FORMAT((Min(CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME)),"dd-mmm-yyyy hh:mm") AS DATE_SORT
FROM CHECKINOUT INNER JOIN USERINFO ON CHECKINOUT.USERID=USERINFO.USERID
WHERE (CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME>=DATEVALUE(PERIOD_START) And CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME<DATEADD("d",1,PERIOD_END) And FORMAT(CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME,"hh:mm")>"12:00" And FORMAT(CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME,"hh:mm")<"13:00")
GROUP BY CHECKINOUT.USERID, USERINFO.Name, USERINFO.SSN, DateValue(CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME), USERINFO.Badgenumber, FORMAT(CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME,"dd")
HAVING (((USERINFO.Badgenumber)<"8000"))
) DB
ORDER BY DB.Name, Min(DB.CHECKTIME)
```